# Device Manager: Update Driver Hangs

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-update

I have administrator access to my windows 10 Pro laptop.  I've opened the Device Manager and discovered that I cannot update any device driver of any kind.  No matter what device I pick (Display Adapters, Keyboards, USB controllers, Printers, etcetera), the request to update driver with "Search automatically for updated driver software" will start the search and then hang; it searches forever and never finds anything.

If I press the "Cancel" button, it will not cancel.  The only way I can make it stop is if I use the task manager to kill the Device Manager.

Any ideas of how to make Device Manager "behave?"

Yes, I do have internet access.  I'm posting this question from the affected machine.

### Update

Now I've noticed that Windows Update also is not working.  It also hangs perpetually!

Comment: [Upgrading](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) Windows 10 should solve these problems

Comment: @spike_66 That is the problem - I cannot update Windows, devices, or anything.

Comment: I waited 30min, and it works. It seems that windows did not implement the right information: "Search automatically for updated driver software" then "wait for the download to finish" and then "wait for the installation to finish". The first one seems to do the whole thing (which is bad, we never know if it's working or if it's frozen.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by disabling Slack from the Windows Startup group. In the startup group it was named "update.exe" and had no icon or other indication that it was Slack related.

Actually, I also disabled Valve's Steam engine from the windows startup group.

After rebooting, I was able to perform windows update and device driver updates.